# find only the first occurence using only grep

Tags: grep, patterns

Suppose i have a file with many words, i want to find only the first word with the pattern "xyz". How do I do it if there are multiple words with this pattern on the same line?
`-m` returns all the words in the first line in which it matches. I need only grep command.

Comment: Do you have many lines in your file? Do you want to find the first word in whole file or the first word in each line?

Comment: it looks like you're asking people to provide you the full command.That's not really how unix.stackexchange works. You should show what you've done, and where you're stuck

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default `grep` prints the **lines** matching a pattern, so if the pattern appears one or more times into a line, `grep` will print that whole line.

Adding the flag `-m 7` will tell `grep` to print only the first 7 lines where the pattern appears.

So this should do what you want (I haven't tested it):

```
grep -o -m 1 xyz myfile | head -1
```

Edit: as pointed out by @Kusalananda, you don't strictly need the `-m` flag but using it means `grep` won't need to parse the whole file, and will output the result faster, especially if `myfile` is a large file.

Comment: Okay. If I assume there is only one such word per line, grep -o -m 1 "exp" filename would do my job right?

Comment: @AtchyutSreekar No, that would'nt, it would fetch all the matching patterns from te first line. You need to pipe that to head -1 to get the real first.

Comment: The `-m 1` is not needed. The matches returned by `-o` will be on separate lines and `head -1` will pick the first match.  Removing `-m 1` will make `grep` go through the entire file (or stop when it notices that it can't write to stdout any longer because `head` has exited), but it make it portable to other Unices that don't have the `-m` flag (BSD).

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question  is in the grep man page:

```
grep -m1 'searchstring' file_name
```

The `-m<number>` option is the key. `-m1` will only show the first match, `-m2` the first 2 occurrences and so on.

Comment: it wont find the first occurrence it would find the first line with the first occurrence.

Comment: yes indeed you do have right.